# Finding number of arrangements of couples not sitting together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways are there to seat $10$ people, consisting of $5$ couples, on a circular table
if...

a. seats are assigned at random.

b. all couples are to get adjacent seats.

c. all couples should not be sitting together.

Now for Part (a) it is just $(10-1)! = 9!$

For Part (b) my attempt is
$4! \cdot (2!)^5$ since there are $5$ couples so $(5-1)! = 4!$ and each of the $5$ couples can change seats between them in $2!$ ways so $(2!)^5$.

But I don't understand part (c). Do we just subtract our Part (b) answer (which is the number of ways of couples sitting together) from Part (a) answer? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say a) is $9!$ instead of $10!$?

Comment: @Darsen we're talking about a circular table, so (n-1)!

Comment: To your question:  There are patterns in which some but not all couples sit together, so $a\neq b+c$.

Comment: What is the question,  is it about probability or number of arrangements?

Comment: @LionHeart it is about permutations sorry I will edit it.

Comment: Your answer to part (a) and (b) is correct. Part (c) is not worded that clearly to me. If all couples do not sit together means some of them can then (a)-(b). If it means that none of the couples can sit together then it is a different problem and you cannot derive from (a) and (b).

Comment: @lulu it is not worded that clearly. "..such that nobody sits next to their spouse" would clearly mean $c \ne a - b$ but one could interpret the question as "all couples do not sit together" means some may, in which case $c = a - b$.

Comment: @MathLover  Ok.  Certainly I read the condition as saying "no couples sit together" but I agree it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to unclear words in the question

1. Case

some couples can sit together in $(10-1)!-4!(2!)^5$ different ways.

2. Case

None of the couples can sit together:

without any restriction they can sit in $(10-1)!$ different ways

a couple can sit together in $\binom{5}{1}8!2!$ different ways

two couples can sit together in $\binom{5}{2}7!(2!)^2$ different ways

three couples can sit together in $\binom{5}{3}6!(2!)^3$ different ways

four couples can sit together in $\binom{5}{4}5!(2!)^4$ different ways

all couples can sit together in $\binom{5}{5}4!(2!)^5$ different ways

and applying inclusive-exlusive principle any couple is not sitting together

$(10-1)!-\binom{5}{1}8!2!+ \binom{5}{2}7!(2!)^2- \binom{5}{3}6!(2!)^3+\binom{5}{4}5!(2!)^4-\binom{5}{5}4!(2!)^5$